# Internet Explorer refreshing iframe

Tags: php, wordpress, internet-explorer, iframe

I am having a very weird issue with IE (test on IE11)
I have a wordpress page that contains a hard coded iframe block that links to a php page which runs a couple of scripts. I used this same code a year ago and it worked fine. Now when I put the iframe into page, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera all displaying it properly. However, when I open the page in IE the iframe is refreshing constantly.

Below is my code for iFrame within WordPress page
http://www.austinweddings.com/bridalextravaganza/dream-wedding-giveaway/

```
<div style="float: none; clear: both; height: 400px;">
     <h2 class="post-title entry-title"><a href="#">Vote for your favorite couple now!</a></h2>
Share this page with your friends on facebook!
    <div class="fb-like" data-share="true" data-show-faces="true" data-action="like" data-layout="standard" data-href="http://www.austinweddings.com/bridalextravaganza/dream-wedding-giveaway/"></div>
    <iframe style="border:0;" src="http://www.texasweddingsltd.com/video-voting/index.php" height="400" width="980"></iframe>
</div>
```

If I visit the http://www.texasweddingsltd.com/video-voting/index.php in IE it displays fine, but in iFrame it goes into infinite refresh loop.

EDIT: I've tested the iFrame on another HTML page in related to WordPress, and it displays it correctly with out refreshing. I narrowing the problem down to the wordpress page itself.

EDIT: Tested the iframe in another WordPress page 
the issue is still present, I am convinced that the issue is somehow caused by the JS calls that exist on both pages.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Do people still use iframes?

Comment: @MarkBaker depends on the nature of the app and browser support required. are you thinking of `<frameset>` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same result in IE11 but my main suggestion is to look into the errors from the console:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am trying to debug the error but it seems the errors stem from jquery files. which are unmodified.

Comment: You are correct. Even if your files are unmodified, there might be some native JS code that simply is not playing nicely with IE11. The errors that I posted refer to an issue which translates to "Hey, I couldn't find jQuery, please include that resource so the `$` can work properly"

Comment: I've narrowed down the issue to Jquery being loaded in both the iframe page and the wordpress page. The conflict of both being loaded in to one page is creating a number of errors which cause the php script that handles the voting get errors. Since the page was poorly written and at this point I need the front end to work, I simply disabled the iframe in IE. Thank you for your help reputation is given.

Comment: Glad I could help point you in the right direction. The Developer tools of any modern browser (IE8 and later lol) are immensely useful. If you ever get into AJAX or Web Sockets then the Network tab is going to be your absolute best friend :) Good luck to you! It is kind of weird that IE11 is having an issue with the `<iframe>` in the way that you're experiencing because an `<iframe>` is supposed to be a standalone DOM unaffected by code outside of it. I guess Microsoft definitely goofed with IE11 lol